# List items to behave like links when cursor hovers

Tags: html, css, listitem, onhover

I have some list items where I want the cursor to change from an arrow to a hand when a user hovers over them. In a sense I want it to look like a link.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the cursor to a pointer.

```
<style type="text/css">
.fakeLink{cursor:pointer}
</style>

<ul>
<li class='fakeLink'>This is not really a link</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks. kinda off the point, but how do I set it so that when one of these li elements gets clicked, it sends a value to JS which then executes code depending on which list item is clicked? (ie, on JS function for multiple list items instead of a unique JS function for each one).

Comment: Using jquery do something like  $('.fakeLink').click(function(){ /* your code to handle all list items here */ });

Comment: @moesef there are a couple of ways to do that, depending on how much you want to pass. Simplest would be the ID of the `<li id="1">` tag (in jQuery): `$('li').click(function(){alert($(this).attr('id'));});` You can do it without jQuery but it involves more code and is better off in its own question.