# Img src to a link

Tags: html

Is it possible to make this chili img to a "a href". The function of the pop up is working fine, but there is no "hand", when you hover the picture.

[Link to my portfolio](https://vouzalis.com/courses/AU/test.php)

**HTML**

```
<img    
    src="/images/thumbs/image1.jpg" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#myModal1" 
    alt="Trolltunga, Norway" 
    width="300px" 
    height="200px"
>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="//placehold.it/1000x600" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function centerModal() {
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
    var $dialog = $(this).find(".modal-dialog");
    var offset = ($(window).height() - $dialog.height()) / 2;
    // Center modal vertically in window
    $dialog.css("margin-top", offset);
}

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', centerModal);
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    $('.modal:visible').each(centerModal);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List items to behave like links when cursor hovers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495578/list-items-to-behave-like-links-when-cursor-hovers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use this code in your css.

```
img:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
img:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Add this to your css

Answer (score 1):

You could add this,

```
img{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

`cursor:pointer` indicates that as link. But actually in your codes there is no `<a> tag` around your image so you can change your `cursor property`.